# Group Rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I need to group by the description so i get in a same row all the days of the week
for example the 'Unjustified' must be shown once in a single row
but when i'm using the Group By statement i'm not getting them concatenate
Can someone help me with this.. Thank You

```
select Emp.ID, 
sum(case when ta_timecarddet.trstype = 6 or ta_timecarddet.trstype = 11 then ta_timecard.scheduledwork else case when ta_timecardlinks.fromtimer = ta_timecard.schedintime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr + ta_timecard.rndminin else case when ta_timecardlinks.totimer = ta_timecard.schedouttime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr - ta_timecard.rndminout else ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr end end end) / ta_timecard.scheduledwork as SchedWork,

case when absence.description is null then case when absence1.description is null then 'Unjustified' else absence1.description end else absence.description end as description,

case when dbo.ta_dayofweek(ta_timecard.schedindate) = 'Mon' then sum(case when ta_timecarddet.trstype = 6 or ta_timecarddet.trstype = 11 then ta_timecard.scheduledwork else case when ta_timecardlinks.fromtimer = ta_timecard.schedintime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr + ta_timecard.rndminin else case when ta_timecardlinks.totimer = ta_timecard.schedouttime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr - ta_timecard.rndminout else ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr end end end) / ta_timecard.scheduledwork end,
case when dbo.ta_dayofweek(ta_timecard.schedindate) = 'Tue' then sum(case when ta_timecarddet.trstype = 6 or ta_timecarddet.trstype = 11 then ta_timecard.scheduledwork else case when ta_timecardlinks.fromtimer = ta_timecard.schedintime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr + ta_timecard.rndminin else case when ta_timecardlinks.totimer = ta_timecard.schedouttime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr - ta_timecard.rndminout else ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr end end end) / ta_timecard.scheduledwork end,
case when dbo.ta_dayofweek(ta_timecard.schedindate) = 'Wed' then sum(case when ta_timecarddet.trstype = 6 or ta_timecarddet.trstype = 11 then ta_timecard.scheduledwork else case when ta_timecardlinks.fromtimer = ta_timecard.schedintime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr + ta_timecard.rndminin else case when ta_timecardlinks.totimer = ta_timecard.schedouttime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr - ta_timecard.rndminout else ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr end end end) / ta_timecard.scheduledwork end,
case when dbo.ta_dayofweek(ta_timecard.schedindate) = 'Thu' then sum(case when ta_timecarddet.trstype = 6 or ta_timecarddet.trstype = 11 then ta_timecard.scheduledwork else case when ta_timecardlinks.fromtimer = ta_timecard.schedintime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr + ta_timecard.rndminin else case when ta_timecardlinks.totimer = ta_timecard.schedouttime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr - ta_timecard.rndminout else ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr end end end) / ta_timecard.scheduledwork end,
case when dbo.ta_dayofweek(ta_timecard.schedindate) = 'Fri' then sum(case when ta_timecarddet.trstype = 6 or ta_timecarddet.trstype = 11 then ta_timecard.scheduledwork else case when ta_timecardlinks.fromtimer = ta_timecard.schedintime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr + ta_timecard.rndminin else case when ta_timecardlinks.totimer = ta_timecard.schedouttime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr - ta_timecard.rndminout else ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr end end end) / ta_timecard.scheduledwork end,
case when dbo.ta_dayofweek(ta_timecard.schedindate) = 'Sat' then sum(case when ta_timecarddet.trstype = 6 or ta_timecarddet.trstype = 11 then ta_timecard.scheduledwork else case when ta_timecardlinks.fromtimer = ta_timecard.schedintime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr + ta_timecard.rndminin else case when ta_timecardlinks.totimer = ta_timecard.schedouttime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr - ta_timecard.rndminout else ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr end end end) / ta_timecard.scheduledwork end,
case when dbo.ta_dayofweek(ta_timecard.schedindate) = 'Sun' then sum(case when ta_timecarddet.trstype = 6 or ta_timecarddet.trstype = 11 then ta_timecard.scheduledwork else case when ta_timecardlinks.fromtimer = ta_timecard.schedintime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr + ta_timecard.rndminin else case when ta_timecardlinks.totimer = ta_timecard.schedouttime then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr - ta_timecard.rndminout else ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr end end end) / ta_timecard.scheduledwork end

from ta_timecarddet
inner join ta_timecard on ta_timecarddet.timecardid = ta_timecard.id
inner join emp on ta_timecard.empid = emp.id
inner join ta_schedulehist on ta_timecard.schedhistid = ta_schedulehist.id
left outer join ta_timecardlinks on ta_timecarddet.id = ta_timecardlinks.tctrsid
left outer join absence on ta_timecard.leavetype = absence.id
left outer join absence absence1 on ta_timecardlinks.leavetype = absence1.id

where  ta_timecarddet.trstype in (1, 5, 6, 11)
and ta_timecard.worktype in (1, 4, 5, 8)

Group BY absence.description, ta_timecard.ScheduledWork, Emp.ID,absence1.description, dbo.ta_dayofweek(ta_timecard.schedindate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch where you are doing your sum, for the sake of not repeating your entire query and trying to make it visible without loads of scrolling I will demonstrate with a single column:

Note, I've also changed your expressions from `case when .. else case when ... else` to a single case expression with multiple whens.

```
sum(case when dbo.ta_dayofweek(ta_timecard.schedindate) = 'Mon' then 
            case when ta_timecarddet.trstype = 6 or ta_timecarddet.trstype = 11 
                    then ta_timecard.scheduledwork 

                when ta_timecardlinks.fromtimer = ta_timecard.schedintime 
                    then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr + ta_timecard.rndminin 

                when ta_timecardlinks.totimer = ta_timecard.schedouttime 
                    then ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr - ta_timecard.rndminout 

                else ta_timecardlinks.effdurationr 
            end 
        else 0 end)  / 
    sum(case when dbo.ta_dayofweek(ta_timecard.schedindate) = 'Mon' 
                then ta_timecard.scheduledwork
            else 0
        end),
```

You will also need to remove `ta_timecard.ScheduledWork` and `dbo.ta_dayofweek(ta_timecard.schedindate)` from your group by.

Essentially you are placing things you want as conditions, but not in the group by **inside** the sum statement, so they don't need to be included in the group by.

Comment: Thank You so much for the explanation. I'm gonna try it and mark your answer if it works